# page load ajax Jquery mobile not show

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

how to debug ajax pageload on change page Jquery mobile, I often faced not showing page somehow?

- noted, on bare link, not using rel="external", then Jqm ussually treat it as ajax load, but on some layout, not show, cause I'm migrate it from desktop site.

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn off the page transitions.As they are quite rough in jquery mobile.
  This may help.

```
 $(document).on( "mobileinit", function() {
        $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "none";
    });
```